# Browser extension to automatically cache all links

Tags: web-browser

Is there any software on mobile or desktop which when a page is loaded, it'll automatically go through all the links and download the pages, so that if I do hit that link, it'll load instantaneously?

Comment: So basically you want the opposite of [How to stop Firefox from automatically making connections without my permission](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-automatically-making-connections) (see "Prefetching")?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely impossible (except in very narrow situations, like your corporate intranet) to improve your browsing experience with this method.

While it is of course technically possible to pre-fetch all links on all pages it will slow down your Internet connection so much that you will most likely have to wait longer for the next page to load, then less.

Example: On this very page there are 176 links. If each of them has 60kB (which is the size of the HTML-Part of this very site) then you have to download ~10mB in HTML per page that you visit. Add to that the amount of Images, CSS, JavaScript and all other media linked on all pages that are linked on any page that you visit and you quickly come to hundreds of megabyte PER PAGE that you visit.

So: There is no such software because its not possible to solve the problem you want to solve with the software you describe.